# Unable to connect to socket IO locally in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am using nodeJs as backend and reactJs as my frontend the thing is I emitted a socket emit function from node

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.emit('quantity_check', 'KR')
```

now the issue is I'm unable to catch the emit

```
let serverUrl = 'localhost:3008'
const socket = socketIOClient(serverUrl);
socket.on("quantity_check", data => this.setState({ kiiii: data }));`  
const socket = socketIOClient(serverUrl);
```

I'm checking this locally even i tried with my ip its not connecting I am not sure where the issue occurs
pc:nodejs and reactjs running on different ports

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:3008`?
How are you importing your socket library in FE?

Comment: import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client"; ya tried but didn't work in console only disconnected is coming as true

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code of you node server file and the react file where are you are listening to the sockets?. Anyway i hope that emit event is inside the `connection`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  io.emit('quantity_check', 'KR')
}
```

and did you use the life cycle method `componentDidMount` to receive message

```
  componentDidMount() {
    socket.on("quantity_check", data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Try something like this.

server

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  io.emit('quantity_check', 'KR');
});
```

Client(React side)

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3008');
export class App extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
   socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socket.connected); 
   });
   socket.on("quantity_checke", data => {
            console.log(data);
     });
 }
   render().......
 }
```

Comment: `var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.emit('quantity_check', 'KR')`  this what i have done in node side